# MigLayout usage

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

A question for those **familiar** with [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/)

sorry couldn't think of a more appropriate name for the question...

I'm trying to create a layout that will end up looking like the following:

```
+---------+---------+
|  btn1   |  btn2   |
+---------+---------+
|                   |
|       btn3        |
|                   |
+-------------------+
```

when the window is resized the components btn1 and btn2 should fill the x-axis (half each), and the component btn3 should fill both the x-axis and all of the available space in the y-axis.

how would you achieve this?

here's some code to start with:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container cp = window.getContentPane();

    cp.setLayout(new MigLayout(""));
    cp.add(new JButton("btn1"), "");
    cp.add(new JButton("btn2"), "");
    cp.add(new JButton("btn3"), "");

    window.pack();
    window.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: if you aren't familiar with MigLayout please test your code before answering. (is that better joachim?)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is pretty easy in MigLayout:

```
setLayout(new MigLayout("fill"));

add(new JButton("button 1"), "w 50%");
add(new JButton("button 2"), "w 50%, wrap");
add(new JButton("button 3"), "grow, push, span");
```

If you read pstanton's original question, I think the layout instructions required are very close to how he formulated it. That's what I like about MigLayout :)

Comment: Very clever - didn't know about the w 50% before.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used miglayout, but it should be something like the following:

```
...
cp.add(new JButton("btn1"));
cp.add(new JButton("btn2"), "wrap");
cp.add(new JButton("btn3"), "span");
...
```

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted but it looks like a correct approach. Looking at documentation, you also need to add this to the constructor: new MigLayout("", "[grow][grow]", "");

Comment: downvoted because it doesn't answer the question. why upvote if you haven't tested the answer and don't know that it works?!

Comment: pilgrim, even with your suggestion btn1 & btn2 don't scale horizontally and btn3 doesn't scale horizontally or vertically.

Answer (score -1):

So do you want something like this:

[image: example image]

The very [Swing Layout Demo](http://www.migcalendar.com/miglayout/swingdemoapp.jnlp) has it, under "Flow Direction"

Here's the code from that sample:

```
JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

tabbedPane.addTab("Layout: flowx, Cell: flowx", createFlowPanel("", "flowx"));
tabbedPane.addTab("Layout: flowx, Cell: flowy", createFlowPanel("", "flowy"));
tabbedPane.addTab("Layout: flowy, Cell: flowx", createFlowPanel("flowy", "flowx"));
tabbedPane.addTab("Layout: flowy, Cell: flowy", createFlowPanel("flowy", "flowy"));

public JPanel createFlowPanel(String gridFlow, String cellFlow) {
    MigLayout lm = new MigLayout("center, wrap 3," + gridFlow,
                                 "[110,fill]",
                                 "[110,fill]");

    JPanel panel = createTabPanel(lm);

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        JButton b = createButton("" + (i + 1));
        b.setFont(b.getFont().deriveFont(20f));
        panel.add(b, cellFlow);
    }

    JButton b = createButton("5:2");
    b.setFont(b.getFont().deriveFont(20f));
    panel.add(b, cellFlow + ",cell 1 1");

    return panel;
}
```

Comment: Oh, I can't post images yet, just delete that space in the reference to see it.

Comment: yeah still not what i'm talking about, plus the code you posted is incomplete and doesn't demonstrate what i'm asking.